# Android Studio Freezes on Generate Signed Apk

Tags: android, apk, freeze, lag, sign

I am trying to sign my `apk` for release. But when I press `Build -> Generate Signed Apk...`, Android Studio freezes, so nothing happens. I can only restart it.

I am using

- Android Studio 3.1.2 stable.
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
- Dell Notebook.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have `minifyEnabled true`? if so change it to false

Comment: same with Android Studio 3.1.3 and 3.2 versions on Linux Mint 18

Comment: That used to happen to me on Ubuntu, how long have you let it sit frozen? I wouldn't touch it for about 2 hours and it would get through it - for me.

Comment: Try clean build and then invalidate cache

Answer (score 1):

I saw a few posts (even on Ubuntu forums) but no answer. That's why I assume it's still not solved. So, according to your goal you could use a hint from *developer android* off-site saying, "You do not need Android Studio to sign your app. [You can sign your app from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signing-manually)".

Answer (score -1):

Two possible solutions:

1- Try to set `minifyEnable false` on build.gradle and if it works so you have wrong rules on the proguard.

2- Uncheck the offline work on Gradle. You can do it by `File->Settings->Build, Executions, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle` uncheck the "offline work". Click apply, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: 1. minifyEnable is set to false and everything works on windows
2. I will check it as soon as I can and let you know if it helps